# I need to copy Data from Google Sheet 1 to a Row in Google Sheet2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, transpose

I am very new to this whole scripting business and I am looking for some advice to solve my problem.
I try to copy data from a column range (H3:H10) in Sheet 1 (Search) to the first free row in sheet 2 (Data). I found this piece of code (from Kos, written 2017), which I thought would do the trick. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to change the code, so it would write the data into the first free row instead of writing the whole data in 1 column in the first free row.

Anyone out here who can help me?

```
function copyPaste() 
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Search");
var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
// get source range
var source = copySheet.getRange(3,8,8,1);
// get destination range
var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,1);
// copy values to destination range
source.copyTo(destination);
// clear source values
source.clearContent();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. What is the image in your question? Can you explain about the detail of it? 2. Can I ask you about the current issue of your script? If an error occurs, please provide it.

Comment: Hello Tanaike, the image would be a screenshot which shows the result in the sheet Data. But it seems, I don't have the rights yet to post pictures. It shows the data I have copied from the Range (Search!H3:H10)  in the Range (Data!A11:A18), (Data!B11:B18), (Data!C11:C18) and so on. That is my main problem. My method takes the data from the column (vertical range), looks for the first empty row (in this case 11) and puts the data then in each column from A11:A18 to H11:H18 instead of paste the data once in A11:H11

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I noticed an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

Copy `H3:H` to First Empty Row in Sheet2

```
function copyColToRow() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs=sh.getRange(3,8,sh.getLastRow()-2,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  const osh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,vs.length).setValues([vs]);
}
```

[Spreadsheet Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

[Array.map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thanks Cooper, that works like a charm. It does exactly what I want it to do. And it makes me realize, that I have a long way to go, before I'll be able to figure out problems like that on my own. Thanks again and have a great day